# Can't update profile information from Area 51

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, area-51

I just decided to update my info while I was hanging out in Area 51.

Then I decided to change it here.

No dice - Area 51 isn't an option. Maybe my profile over there wears a tinfoil hat?

Comment: They're different systems... Area 51 is on an older version of the site and isn't really updated any more. You have to be on Area 51 to change your profile there.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? You changed it here, clicked "Save and copy to all communities", and it wasn't updated in Area 51?

Comment: I updated it on Area 51 and couldn't import it to my stackexchange profile.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, Area 51 is a separate codebase. It's also heavily outdated. Currently we can push a profile update from Q&A to Area 51, but not the other way around, and there are no plans to add that functionality, sorry.