# Profile changes in Q&A are not pushed to Area 51

Tags: bug, profile-page, area-51, profile-sync

I just noticed that the info text on [my Area 51 profile](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/6603/christian-specht) is an older version of the text in [my Q&A profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6884/christian-specht).

I found [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/278037/162055) from April 2016 where Adam Lear says:

> Area 51 is a separate codebase. It's also heavily outdated. Currently we can push a profile update from Q&A to Area 51, but not the other way around

I think the pushing isn't working anymore.
I just updated my text on SO again and it was changed in all my accounts, except Area 51.

Comment: Well, for the same reason previously mentioned… this isn't real likely to be fixed. A51 is basically in critical-bugfix-only mode.

Comment: Okay, I changed my Area 51 profile manually...